# How to make a Update command with SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, tkinter

I'm having trouble setting up my application. I want help developing the update command in the database. I've tried it in several ways, but for the simple reason that I'm using the TextBox widget, the process is much more complicated. As you can see, I did all the hard work of inserting and deleting values, but I just need to know how to update them.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import sqlite3


class cadastro:
    # connection dir property----------------------------------------------------
    # propriedade do dir de conexão------------------------------------------------
    db_name = 'database.db'

    def __init__(self, window):

        # Initializations ----------------------------------------------  
        #Inicializações --------------------------------------------------
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('cadastro DataSet')


        # Creating a Frame Container ------------------------------------------------  
        #Criando um Contêiner de Quadro-------------------------------------------
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Registrar novo cadastro')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)


        # Name Input------------------------------------------------------
        Label(frame, text = 'Name: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.name = Text(frame, width=20,height=3)
        self.name.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.name.focus()
        self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


        self.scrollb = Scrollbar(frame, command=self.name.yview)
        self.scrollb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns', columnspan=3)
        self.name['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollb.set


        Label(frame, text = 'Description: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.description = Text(frame, width=20,height=3)
        self.description.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.description.focus()
        self.description.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.scrollb = Scrollbar(frame, command=self.description.yview)
        self.scrollb.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ns', columnspan=3)
        self.description['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollb.set


        Label(frame, text = 'Local: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self.local = Text(frame,width=20,height=3)
        self.local.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.local.focus()
        self.local.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        self.scrollb = Scrollbar(frame, command=self.local.yview)
        self.scrollb.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='ns', columnspan=3)
        self.local['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollb.set


        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame,columns=("Name", "Description"))
        self.tree.heading("#0", text="Name", anchor= CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#1", text="Description", anchor= CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#2", text="Local", anchor= CENTER)        
        self.tree.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 5, ipady=10)

        self.scrollb = Scrollbar(frame, command=self.tree.yview)
        self.scrollb.grid(row=4, column=5, sticky='ns', rowspan=1)
        self.tree['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollb.set

        # Button Add cadastro --------------------------------------------------
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Inserir', command = self.add_cadastro).grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W + E)
        #Botão para excluir cadastro--------------------------------------------
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'DELETE', command = self.delete_cadastro).grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = W + E)
        #Botão para atualizar cadastro------------------------------------------
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'EDIT', command = self.edit_cadastro).grid(row = 5, column = 3, sticky = W + E)

        # Output Messages ------------------------------------------------------
        # Mensagens de Saída ---------------------------------------------------
        self.message = Label(text = '', fg = 'red')
        self.message.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W + E)


        # Filling the Rows-------------------------------------------------------
        # Preenchendo as filas----------------------------------------------------
        self.get_cadastro()

    # Function to Execute Database Querys----------------------------------------------
    # Função para executar bancos de dados --------------------------------------------
    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cadastro (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , name TEXT, description TEXT, local TEXT)")
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

    def get_cadastro(self):
        # cleaning Table ----------------------------------------------------------------
        # mesa de limpeza------------------------------------------------------------------
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element) 

        query = 'SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY name DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)


        for row in db_rows:

            self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = (row[2],row[3]))

    # Validação De Entrada De Usuário -----------------------------------------------------
    def validation(self):
        return (self.name.get(1.0, END)),(self.description.get(1.0, END), (self.local.get(1.0, END)))

    def add_cadastro(self):
        if self.validation():
            query = 'INSERT INTO cadastro VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters =  (self.name.get(1.0, END), self.description.get(1.0, END), self.local.get(1.0, END))
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.message['text'] = 'cadastro {} added Successfully'.format(self.name.get(1.0, END))
            self.name.delete(1.0, END)
            self.description.delete(1.0, END)
            self.local.delete(1.0, END)
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Name and Data is Required'
        self.get_cadastro()

    def delete_cadastro(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
           self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Please select a Record'
            return
        self.message['text'] = ''
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        query = 'DELETE FROM cadastro WHERE name = ?'
        self.run_query(query, (name, ))
        self.message['text'] = 'Record {} deleted Successfully'.format(name)
        self.get_cadastro()

    def edit_cadastro(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Please, select Record'
            return
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        description = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        local = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][1]

        self.edit_wind = Toplevel()
        self.edit_wind.title = 'Edit Civilization'
        frame2 = LabelFrame(self.edit_wind, text = 'Registros atuais,janela de visualização avançada.')
        frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)

        self.nomelab = Label(frame2, text = 'Name: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)


        message2 = Text(frame2, height=5, width=50)
        message2.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        message2.insert(END, name)
        message2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

        self.descriptlab = Label(frame2, text = 'Description: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)

        message3 = Text(frame2, height=5, width=34)
        message3.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        message3.insert(END, description)
        message3.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

        self.locallab = Label(frame2, text = 'Local: ').grid(row = 5, column = 0)

        message4 = Text(frame2, height=5, width=34)
        message4.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        message4.insert(END, local)
        message4.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()

    application = cadastro(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is update query or atleast show what you tried

Comment: MySQL 's manual about [UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)  and here you [learn](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/manual-conventions.html) how to read the manual's certain typographical conventions:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function like:

```
def update_castro(self, old_name, message2, message3, message4):
        message2 = message2.get(1.0, END)
        message3 = message3.get(1.0, END)
        message4 = message4.get(1.0, END)

        query = 'UPDATE cadastro set name = ?, description = ?, local = ? WHERE name = ?'
        self.run_query(query, (message2, message3, message4, old_name ))

        self.get_cadastro()
        self.edit_wind.destroy()
```

and add a button named **Update** in `edit_wind`:

```
        ttk.Button(
            frame2, text = 'Update', 
            command = lambda: self.update_castro(name, message2, message3, message4)
        ).grid(row = 7, column = 3, sticky = W + E)
```

Or use the code below, directly :)

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import sqlite3


class cadastro:
    # connection dir property----------------------------------------------------
    # propriedade do dir de conexão------------------------------------------------
    db_name = 'database.db'

    def __init__(self, window):

        # Initializations ----------------------------------------------  
        #Inicializações --------------------------------------------------
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('cadastro DataSet')


        # Creating a Frame Container ------------------------------------------------  
        #Criando um Contêiner de Quadro-------------------------------------------
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Registrar novo cadastro')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)


        # Name Input------------------------------------------------------
        Label(frame, text = 'Name: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.name = Text(frame, width=20,height=3)
        self.name.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.name.focus()
        self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


        self.scrollb = Scrollbar(frame, command=self.name.yview)
        self.scrollb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns', columnspan=3)
        self.name['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollb.set


        Label(frame, text = 'Description: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.description = Text(frame, width=20,height=3)
        self.description.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.description.focus()
        self.description.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.scrollb = Scrollbar(frame, command=self.description.yview)
        self.scrollb.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ns', columnspan=3)
        self.description['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollb.set


        Label(frame, text = 'Local: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self.local = Text(frame,width=20,height=3)
        self.local.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.local.focus()
        self.local.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        self.scrollb = Scrollbar(frame, command=self.local.yview)
        self.scrollb.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='ns', columnspan=3)
        self.local['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollb.set


        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame,columns=("Name", "Description"))
        self.tree.heading("#0", text="Name", anchor= CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#1", text="Description", anchor= CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#2", text="Local", anchor= CENTER)        
        self.tree.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 5, ipady=10)

        self.scrollb = Scrollbar(frame, command=self.tree.yview)
        self.scrollb.grid(row=4, column=5, sticky='ns', rowspan=1)
        self.tree['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollb.set

        # Button Add cadastro --------------------------------------------------
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Inserir', command = self.add_cadastro).grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W + E)
        #Botão para excluir cadastro--------------------------------------------
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'DELETE', command = self.delete_cadastro).grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = W + E)
        #Botão para atualizar cadastro------------------------------------------
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'EDIT', command = self.edit_cadastro).grid(row = 5, column = 3, sticky = W + E)

        # Output Messages ------------------------------------------------------
        # Mensagens de Saída ---------------------------------------------------
        self.message = Label(text = '', fg = 'red')
        self.message.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W + E)


        # Filling the Rows-------------------------------------------------------
        # Preenchendo as filas----------------------------------------------------
        self.get_cadastro()

    # Function to Execute Database Querys----------------------------------------------
    # Função para executar bancos de dados --------------------------------------------
    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cadastro (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , name TEXT, description TEXT, local TEXT)")
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

    def get_cadastro(self):
        # cleaning Table ----------------------------------------------------------------
        # mesa de limpeza------------------------------------------------------------------
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element) 

        query = 'SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY name DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)


        for row in db_rows:

            self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = (row[2],row[3]))

    # Validação De Entrada De Usuário -----------------------------------------------------
    def validation(self):
        return (self.name.get(1.0, END)),(self.description.get(1.0, END), (self.local.get(1.0, END)))

    def add_cadastro(self):
        if self.validation():
            query = 'INSERT INTO cadastro VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters =  (self.name.get(1.0, END), self.description.get(1.0, END), self.local.get(1.0, END))
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.message['text'] = 'cadastro {} added Successfully'.format(self.name.get(1.0, END))
            self.name.delete(1.0, END)
            self.description.delete(1.0, END)
            self.local.delete(1.0, END)
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Name and Data is Required'
        self.get_cadastro()

    def delete_cadastro(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
           self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Please select a Record'
            return
        self.message['text'] = ''
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        query = 'DELETE FROM cadastro WHERE name = ?'
        self.run_query(query, (name, ))
        self.message['text'] = 'Record {} deleted Successfully'.format(name)
        self.get_cadastro()

    def edit_cadastro(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Please, select Record'
            return
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        description = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        local = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][1]

        self.edit_wind = Toplevel()
        self.edit_wind.title = 'Edit Civilization'
        frame2 = LabelFrame(self.edit_wind, text = 'Registros atuais,janela de visualização avançada.')
        frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)

        self.nomelab = Label(frame2, text = 'Name: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)


        message2 = Text(frame2, height=5, width=50)
        message2.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        message2.insert(END, name)
        message2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

        self.descriptlab = Label(frame2, text = 'Description: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)

        message3 = Text(frame2, height=5, width=34)
        message3.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        message3.insert(END, description)
        message3.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

        self.locallab = Label(frame2, text = 'Local: ').grid(row = 5, column = 0)

        message4 = Text(frame2, height=5, width=34)
        message4.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        message4.insert(END, local)
        message4.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

        ttk.Button(
            frame2, text = 'Update', 
            command = lambda: self.update_castro(name, message2, message3, message4)
        ).grid(row = 7, column = 3, sticky = W + E)

    def update_castro(self, old_name, message2, message3, message4):
        message2 = message2.get(1.0, END)
        message3 = message3.get(1.0, END)
        message4 = message4.get(1.0, END)

        query = 'UPDATE cadastro set name = ?, description = ?, local = ? WHERE name = ?'
        self.run_query(query, (message2, message3, message4, old_name ))

        self.get_cadastro()
        self.edit_wind.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()

    application = cadastro(window)
    window.mainloop()
```